# How to fix Not Found: /blogs/like when adding Ajax to like button

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am trying to make the like button in the `post_detail.html` page clicked without refreshing the page so, I included the like section in a separate HTML called `like-section.html`. The problem is now I am getting a `Not Found: /blogs/like`

when I click on the like button and it doesn't change anything when I click it except in the terminal I see this error `Not Found: /blogs/like`

How do I solve this error and what am I missing

Here is the model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ------------------------------
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')
```

Here is the views.py

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    post_obj = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')

        try:
            post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Not found'}, status=404)
        else:
            if user in post_obj.liked.all():
                post_obj.liked.remove(user)
            else:
                post_obj.liked.add(user)

            like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post_id)
            if not created:
                if like.value == 'Like':
                    like.value = 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
            like.save()
            context = {
                'post_id': post_id,
            }
            if request.is_ajax:
                html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context,
                                        request=request)
                return JsonResponse({'form': html})
            elif request.method == 'GET':
                post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
                try:
                    post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
                except Post.DoesNotExist:
                    return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Not found'}, status=404)
```

Here is the like-section.html

```
          <form action="{% url 'blog:like-post' %}" method="POST" class="like-form" id="{{post.id}}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value='{{post.id}}'>

            {% if user not in post.liked.all %}
              <a id="like" class="bwhite sm-button" style="color: grey; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none;">
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up" type="submit"></i>
              </a>
            {% else %}
              <a id="like" class="bwhite sm-button" style="color: blue;background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none;" >
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up" type="submit"></i>
              </a>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="like-count{{post.id}}">{{ post.num_likes }} Likes</div>
          </form>
```

Here is the script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            let display = false
            $(".cmt_btn").click(function () {
                if (display===false) {
                    $(this).next(".comment-box").show("fast");
                    display=true
                } else {
                    $(this).next(".comment-box").hide("fast");
                    display=false
                }
            });
        });
  </script>
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var pk = $(this).attr('value');
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "blog:like-post" %}',
            data: {'post_id':pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
              $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
              console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
            },
            error: function(rs, e){
              console.log(rs.responseText);
            },
          });
        });
  </script>
```

Trying to debug it I tried `console.log(url)` i got `{"detail": "Not found"}`
Here is the urls.py

```
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('blogs/like', like_post, name='like-post'),
```